# Angular Unknown Provider after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, bundling-and-minification

I'm having problems after the minification of my angular code, like $injector:modulerr and similar.
I'm using a custom module, have a look here https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/blob/master/src/angular-local-storage.js, that is injected in this way:

```
var app = angular.module('MyNewApp', ['LocalStorageModule'] );

app.config(function(localStorageServiceProvider){
  localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('myNewApp');
  localStorageServiceProvider.setStorageType('sessionStorage');
})
```

After the minification it doesn't work, so I'm trying something like this below to fix:

```
app.config(["localStorageService", function(localStorageServiceProvider){
  ..
})
```

And

```
angular.module('MyNewApp', [] )
// and also .module('LazyDogzApp', ['LocalStorageModule'] )
   .config(['localStorageService', function(localStorageServiceProvider)
   ...
   }]);
```

but I alway get an error $injector:unpr Unknown Provider: localStorageService

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: You forget to add the `LocalStorageModule` when you define `MyNewApp` module

Comment: @Rodson No I tried it too, but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
app.config(["localStorageServiceProvider", function(localStorageServiceProvider){
   ...
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a closing `]` between `}` and `)`?

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are using gulp, add [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)